# Why is my "Session Stop" count higher than my "Session Start" count for the same period in AWS Pinpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm testing the service myself, and the sessions were all started / stopped within the same period.

I enabled Pinpoint with:

```
Amplify.configure(awsConfig);
Analytics.autoTrack('session', {
  enable: true,
  provider: 'AWSPinpoint'
});
```

But, there are two problems:

1. When I visit my site, I don't immediately see the "Session Start" metric increase for that day.
2. The "Session End" metric is higher than Session Start for the same period (4 vs. 30).

I'm using the "Filters" to review metrics, and my guess it, they're reprocessed at regular intervals and not immediately available.  That explains the realtime issue.

As for #2, I do not know why I have more Session Ends than I have Session Starts.

Also, is PinPoint a well-known / common industry tool, or do most teams use something else like Google Analytics?

All advice is appreciate,
Thank you!